# Can't get Mathematica to use FourierTransform in the way I want it to

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I'm an EE working with signals and systems trying to get Mathematica to do a few basic functions to see if I could use it regularly in my work. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
xt = 10*UnitBox[10*t] + 20*Cos[30*π*t];  
xf = FourierTransform[xt, t, f, FourierParameters -> {0, -2*π}]
```

Now when I run this code Mathematica insists that:

```
xf = 10*DiracDelta[-15 + f] + 10* DiracDelta[15 + f] + Sinc[(f*π)/10]
```

However, I disagree with that. I believe that:

```
xf = 10*DiracDelta[-15 + f] + 10* DiracDelta[15 + f] + Sinc[(f)/10]
```

There is no π in the `Sinc` function

But after a solid 30 minutes of playing with parameters/equations, I've not had luck getting Mathematica to agree with me. Either the transformation I calculated is wrong, I need to change a setting in Mathematica, or Mathematica doesn't know how to Fourier transform unit rectangles.

Can anyone see the problem? I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation, using `FourierParameters->{a,b}` is equivalent to:

$$\sqrt{\frac{\left| b\right| }{(2 \pi )^{1-a}}} \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \
f(t) e^{i b t \omega } \, dt$$

or, with your parameters:

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } f(t) e^{-2 \pi  i t \omega } \, dt$$

Let's see what Mathematica does with this integral when `f[t] = 10 UnitBox[10 t]`:

```
Integrate[10 UnitBox[10 t] Exp[-2Pi I f t], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]//InputForm

(* (10*Sin[(f*Pi)/10])/(f*Pi) *)
```

Compare this to the answer you disagree with:

```
FunctionExpand[Sinc[f Pi/10]]//InputForm

(* (10*Sin[(f*Pi)/10])/(f*Pi) *)
```

I think Mathematica is giving you the correct result.

Comment: I think I have found the answer. Mathematica defines the Sinc function differently than how I was taught. Maybe this is only commonplace in my field, but Sinc(x) to me means Sin(Pi*x)/(Pi*x) however Mathematica calls Sinc(x)=sin(x)/x. This is why I think I have an extra Pi in my xf result.

Comment: @Justin, yes, that seems to be a DSP thing; in a number of other places, $\operatorname{sinc}$ does not have that factor of $\pi$.

Comment: If anyone reading would like to learn more, it's actually the first thing the wikipedia page mentions! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function

Answer (score 2):

The Dirac functions always come from the Fourier transform of the cosine (and sines also). So Breaking you function into two parts:

```
I2 = FourierTransform[20*Cos[30*Pi*t], t, f, FourierParameters -> {0, -2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we will do the Box part by `hand`

```
I1= Integrate[10*UnitBox[10*t] Exp[I (-2 Pi) f t], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you add them

```
I3 = (I1 + I2) // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to Fourier Transform applied to both as you had it:

```
xt = 10*UnitBox[10*t] + 20*Cos[30*\[Pi]*t];
xf = FourierTransform[xt, t, f, FourierParameters -> {0, -2*\[Pi]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 FullSimplify[xf - I3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica is right again!